# How to perform a search in an SQL database with a java application?

Tags: java, mysql, database, search

I'm planning to build a very very simple java application done on Netbeans that accepts basic individual information like ID number, name, and address and stores it on an sql database.

I want to put a search function on my program that accepts ID numbers. When the user inputs the ID number that is stored in the database, it will show the Name and address on a pop up message dialog.

I know this is possible but can you link me to some guides or documentations about the search function? or maybe you could give me a very short example of a sample code done in the search button?

Comment: Is this going to be for simple queries like `ID = ?` or more dynamic and complex queries based upon whatever fields are filled in?

Comment: Yeah just a very simple query like that. No need for dynamic search. The program just accepts the exact ID number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/)

It is using classes such as `Connection` and `PreparedStatement`

Pseudo-code being

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME FROM DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = ?";

dbConnection = getDBConnection();
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1001);

// execute select SQL stetement
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

try {
  while (rs.next()) {
    String userid = rs.getString("USER_ID");
    String username = rs.getString("USERNAME");
    System.out.println("userid : " + userid);
  }

  } catch (SQLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    preparedStatement.close();
    dbConnection.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/

Look into how to use JDBC.

A very basic example:

```
    Connection c = null; //need to initialize a java.sql.Connection from JDBC.


    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name = ?";        
    PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, "John Smith");

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    List<String> matchingNames = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rs.next())
    {
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        matchingNames.add(name);
    }       

    for (String name: matchingNames)
    {
        //Display dialog.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jdbc-tutorials/) is a very good JDBC tutorial. JDBC is the way that java uses database, but this is so basic that almost no real project use JDBC directly.

If you want to learn more, try [MyBatis](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/mybatis-tutorial-crud-operations-and-mapping-relationships-part-1.html) and [Hibernate](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/) which are the most popular ORM framework, and both of them are based on JDBC.

PS. http://www.mkyong.com/ this site has many good tutorials for Java developer